# Unicode characters in email address - phpmailer - php

Tags: php, unicode, phpmailer

I have a script that sends a confirmation email to people who signed up to a competition, via a form.

The email is a property of an object, and is set in the following way in the constructor of that object:

> ```
> $this->email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
> $this->email = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($this->email, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $this->email);
> ```

Note that the conversion is something I put there to try an solve this problem, but it did not work.

It is then sent via a public function on that same object:
*Look below to see the class emailMessage, which is an extension of PHPMailer*

```
public function sendMail($subject, $message)
{
  global $CFG;
  $mail = new emailMessage();
  $mail->Subject  = $subject;
  $mail->setContent($message);
  $sentMails = 0;
  $errors = "";

  $mail->AddAddress($this->email);

  if(!$mail->Send())
  {
    $errorCount++;
    $errors .= 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
  }
  else 
  {
    $sentMails++;
  }

  $mail->ClearAddresses();

  if($sentMails > 0)
    return true;
  if($errors != "")
  {
    echo $errors;
    return false;
  }
}
```

And this all works jolly nice must of the time, however, **whenever `$this->email` contains special characters, in this case Æ, Ø, or Å, the script gives me the following error:**

`Mailer error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.`

I've tried all sorts of string encoding, and non seems to work.

I should point out that danish domains (.dk) are allowed to contain these special characters.

I really hope someone can tell me what the problem is! Thanks for reading.

Last but not least: As promised, the extension to PHPMailer:

```
class emailMessage extends PHPMailer
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->CharSet="UTF-8";
    $this->AddEmbeddedImage(calculateRelativePath() . "img/camp_carnival.png", "camp_carnival");
    $this->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    //$this->Host     = $CFG->smtpServer; // SMTP server
    //$this->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $this->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $this->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
    $this->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $this->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $this->Username   = "x@domain.com";  // GMAIL username
    $this->Password   = "";            // GMAIL password
    $this->SetFrom('x@domain.com', 'Lasse Rørbæk');
    $this->AddReplyTo("x@domain.com","Lasse Rørbæk");
    $this->WordWrap = 50;
    $this->IsHTML(true);
  }

  public function setContent($content)
  {
    $this->Body = '
      <table width="100%" style="background-color:rgb(239,233,217);">
        <tr>
          <td height="15">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" style="margin:20px 0px 30px 0px;">
            <center>
              <img width="80%" alt="Camp*Carnival" src="cid:camp_carnival"/>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:100%;padding:20px 70px;">
            <div style="margin:auto;width:65%;border:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);border-radius: 7px;padding:10px 7px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFFFFFF,endColorstr=#7FFFFFFF);">
              ' . $content . '
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you try validating one of the troublesome addresses against [is_email](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/)?  If that library rejects the mail, then the address you are providing is not compliant with the current generation of email-governing RFCs.  If it *does* pass, then you might want to file a bug with the PHPMailer folks.  You should also take a look at [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Qr5PP.png Change your password dude.

Comment: @Charles interestingly the php version of `is_email` returns false but java version true, it seems the php version doesn't handle utf8 :X

Comment: Yes, that was my real data, and no I wasn't thinking. Changed the password. Thanks for pointing it out! :)

Comment: Okay, so It's not a valid email. Any suggestions as to actually sending an email to the poor fellow stupid enough to buy a domain with non-ASCII letters? ... I'm thinking that an URL with æøå in it properbly uses some form of character replacement then, although I can't seem to find any documentation of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That address doesn't pass phpmailer's `ValidateAdress` function, where the regex doesn't even have utf8 support enabled. Though it still won't validate even with utf8 mode enabled.

You should enable exceptions so you see them. You can enable exceptions by passing `true` to the constructor:

```
class emailMessage extends PHPMailer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(true);
```

With this you see should see the exception for invalid address.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :). I tried this, and as you correctly stated I got the exception for an invalid email address. This does not, however, solve my problem. I still need some way of sending an email to these addresses. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Fireworm you need to use some different library or modify phpmailer

Comment: I was thinking that I might be able to send mail to them by replacing the æøå charecters with something else in the address. If I forexample go to this address: http://æøåhghg.dk/ I actually go to http://xn--hghg-poaf0k.dk/. If I could find that translation table somewhere, I might be able to translate the addresses myself. Anybody have a clue where I might find it?

Comment: No, that won't work either. The fault also appears when æøå appears before @, so translating the domain won't help any. If anybody is interested, I did find a tool for translating domains: http://phlymail.com/en/downloads/idna-convert.html